# php function return empty value when param set to a variable

Tags: php

I've been wondering why my function return to an empty value(NULL) when putting variable parameter on it..

function: (return empty value)

```
private static function typeObjectId($type_param) {

    ...
    ...
    (some code)
    for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
        if($results[$i]->type == $type_param) {
            $some_var = $results[$i]->objectId; 
            return $some_var;
        }
```

function: (return a value)

```
private static function typeObjectId() {

    ...
    ...
    (some code)
    for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
        if($results[$i]->type == 'Lorem') {
            $some_var = $results[$i]->objectId; 
            return $some_var;
        }
```

caller: (return empty value)

```
public function functionName() {
    $var_param = 'Lorem';
    $var = self::typeObjectId($var_param);
    return $var;            
}
```

caller: (Return a value)

```
public function createPostImage() {
    $var = self::typeObjectId();
    return $var;            
}
```

P.S
The value that return is coming from a cloud storage..
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: what does `var_dump($type_param);` show to you within `typeObjectId($type_param) {` function ?

Comment: null, sorry late reply

Comment: make sure that `$type_param` has not been overwritten by some earlier code

Comment: it wasn't sir, the string 'Lorem' ex. in this code is an actual value in cloud storage, i think that's the problem, because before the function was called it query the storage, i think